Can't set a custom platform toolset on Visual Studio 2022
I've been trying to set Clang++ as my custom platform toolset but it still not working.
In general properties I do have this set "clang++ -std=c++20 -I"C:\Program Files\msys64\mingw64\bin\clang++.exe"
(not installed)", but as you can see it's not working properly.
Then I have either on C++ and Linker settings this "C:\Program Files\msys64\mingw64\bin\clang++". I don't think there's my problem, but I can't figure out how to set this, Clang is actually installed.
I tried to use MSYS2 Clang as my Visual Studio 2022 compiler but it didn't show as installed when it actually is.

Did you follow the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/clang-support-msbuild?view=msvc-170

What do you mean by "(Not installed)"?

VS2022 is 64-bit now, I wonder if that might be something to do with it?

I do have Clang installed by VS Installer, but I'm trying manually
And it says (Not installed) because that's what the main settings drop there, I didn't write that
And I know, and I'm working on 64 bit

Visual Studio is a compiler and IDE.  Why are you using Clang instead of Microsoft compiler?

I do because I'm learning both, and I want to use both then even if it's complex

@ThomasMatthews Clang targets many more platforms than VC++ does.

Visual Studio has clang (LLVM toolset) built in. You just don't need the MSYS2 version. Seems like you are trying too hard to fix what is not broken. :-)

And anyway, doesn't the MSYS2 installer strongly recommend "C:\msys64" as the base directory, and to avoid "C:\Program Files"? (Because Linux programs don't like spaces in their file names)
